# MATLAB, mex files, Fortran, warnings and errors

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I'm not quite seeing the issue I'm having, and I've tried suggestions I've seen in other forum posts.  I am trying to write a (fortran) mex file, per request of my boss.  However, I was getting warnings when passing a matrix to my computational routine.  If I ignored the warning, my MATLAB shut down.  So now I'm trying a simpler program, an inner product.  However, I am still getting the warning: "Expected a procedure at (1)" where (1) is at 'call innerProd(x,y,c)' underneath the x.  I'm not sure what that means...  I've included my code.

```
#include "fintrf.h"
C======================================================================
#if 0      
C
C     innerProd.F
C     .F file needs to be preprocessed to generate .for equivalent
C     
#endif 
C
C     innerProd.F
C     calculates the inner product

C     This is a MEX file for MATLAB.
C     Copyright 1984-2011 The MathWorks, Inc.
C     $Revision: 1.12.2.9 $

C======================================================================
C     Gateway routine      
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
     implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer:: plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer:: nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer:: mxCreateDoubleMatrix, mxGetPr,mxGetM, mxGetData
      integer:: mxIsNumeric

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:   
      mwPointer:: x_ptr, y_ptr, c_ptr 

C     Array information:
     mwSize:: m

C     Arguments for computational routine:      
      real*8::  x,y,c

C----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Check for proper number of arguments. 
      if (nrhs .ne. 2) then
         call mexErrMsgTxt('Error.')
      elseif (nlhs .ne. 1) then
         call mexErrMsgTxt('One output required.')
      endif

C     Check to see if inputs are numeric.
      if (mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) .ne. 1 ) then
         call mexErrMsgTxt('Input # 1 is not a numeric array.')
      elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(2)) .ne. 1) then
         call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #2 is not a numeric array.')
      endif

C     Find dimensions of mxArrays
      m=mxGetM(prhs(1))

C     create Fortran arrays from the input arguments      
      x_ptr=mxGetData(prhs(1))
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_ptr,x,m)
      y_ptr= mxGetData(prhs(2))   
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(y_ptr,y,m)

C     create matrix for the return argument
     plhs(1) =mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)      
     c_ptr= mxGetPr(plhs(1))

C     Call the computational subroutine.
     call innerProd(x,y,c)

C     Load the output into a MATLAB array.
     call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(c, c_ptr, 1)

     return
     end subroutine mexFunction

C----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Computational routine
      subroutine innerProd(x,y,c)
      implicit none

  real*8:: x,y,temp,c
  integer:: i,m

  do i=1,m
  temp=temp+x(i)*y(i)
  end do

  c = temp
  return
  end subroutine innerProd
```

I'm just learning this for the first time, and I would appreciate any suggestions.  Even if it is where to look for solutions.  I've looked through MATLAB mex Fortran aids online.  There isn't any help there.  I can't get the function to run, so I can't use print statements which is a good way to debug.  I think mex has a print function, I will try to get that to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you haven't anywhere declared the arguments of `innerProd` as arrays.  That holds for the *actual* arguments `x` and `y` in the subroutine `mexFunction` and the *dummy* arguments `x` and `y` in `innerProd` itself.

So, in `innerProd` the expression `x(i)` isn't referencing the `i`-th element of the `real*8` array `x`, but the `real*8` result of the *function* `x` with argument `i`.  As the `x` you've passed isn't a function (procedure), this is an error.

There are ways to solve this, but all involve declaring the dummy arguments as arrays.  Which brings up another point.

You have in `innerProd`

```
integer:: i,m

do i=1,m
  temp=temp+x(i)*y(i)
end do
```

where `m` is not defined.  Crucially, from `mexfunction` you're expecting the compiler to know that `m` is the size of the arrays `x` and `y`: this isn't true.  `m` is a variable local to `innerProd`.  Instead you may want to pass it as an argument to the subroutine and use that to dimension the arrays:

```
subroutine innerProd(x,y,c,m)
  implicit none

  integer :: m
  real*8:: x(m),y(m),temp,c
  ...
end subroutine
```

[You could, of course, use *assumed-shape* arrays (and the `SIZE` intrinsic), but that's an additional complication requiring more substantial changes.]  You also need to think about how to declare arrays appropriately in `mexfunction`, noting that the call to `mxCopyPtrToReal8` also requires an array argument.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I had declared the size within innerProd as well as where x and y are first declared in the mexFunction.  I got this error: Variable 'm' cannot appear in the expression at (1).  Then I use the keyword external to get the error: EXTERNAL attribute conflicts with DIMENSION attribute at (1).  When I remove any size declaration outside of innerProd, I get the warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'x' at (1) (rank-1 and scalar).  That is when I removed the size declaration within the function to get the above issues. any suggestions?

Comment: You mean that the error occurs using `x(m)` in `mexfunction` rather than in `innerProd`?  This will indeed be an error (and using `external` is unrelated): the array size must be a constant expression.  You can either use allocatable arrays (in `mexfunction`) or a "large enough" constant size (passing just the required first `m` for the call).  That's probably another question, which should previously be solved.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get the Fortran code to work for innerProd, but I did get C code to work.  I recommend, if you are having issues with Fortran, to use C.  It seems that Matlab is more flexible when it comes to mex files and C.  Here is the code:

```
#include "mex.h"

/*
* innerProd.c
*
*Computational function that takes the inner product of two vectors.
*
*Mex-file for MATLAB.
*/

void innerProd(double *x, double *y,double *c,int m){
 double temp;
 int i;

for(i=0; i < m; i++){
temp = temp + x[i]*y[i];
}

*c=temp;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
double *x, *y, *c;
size_t m;

/*check for proper number of arguments.*/
if(nrhs != 2){
mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:innerProd:invalidNumInputs","Two input required.");
}

/*The input must be a noncomplex double vector.*/
m = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
if(!mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || m==1){
mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:innerProd:inputNotRealDouble","Input must be noncomplex double vector");
}

/*create return argument */
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0);
c=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

/*Assign pointers to each input and output. */
x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
y=mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

/*call subroutine*/
innerProd(x,y,c,m);

}
```

I will still take suggestions on the Fortran code above, though.  I'd like to know how to get it to work.  Thanks!