# Matrix multiplication program: Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, matrix-multiplication

I am a very new user to Fortran 90. I am learning how to program. Currently, I am trying to create a program to do matrix multiplication. But, I am getting an error.

```
Program Matrix_Multiplication
    Implicit None
    Real, Dimension(2:2) :: A, B, C
    Integer :: i, j, k
    A = 0.0
    B = 0.0
    C = 0.0
    do i = 1, 2
    do j = 1, 2
        Read (80, *) A
        Read (90, *) B
        Write (100, *) A, B
    end do
    end do
    Call subC(A, B, C)
    Write (110, *) C
End Program Matrix_Multiplication

Subroutine subC(A, B, C)
    Implicit None
    Real, Intent(IN) :: A, B
    Integer :: i, j, k
    Real, Intent(OUT) :: C
    do i = 1, 2
    do j = 1, 2
        C = C(i, j) + (A(i, j)*B(j, i))
    end do
    end do
    return
End Subroutine
```

On compiling:

> C(i, j) = (A(i, k)*B(k, j)) 1 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Comment: You need to declare the arguments in `subC` as arrays, much as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/28049298/3157076.

Comment: other issues, `C` is used without being initialised. the `C=..` statement is an assignment to the entire array, syntactically valid but surely not what you intend

Comment: @Marcus what was the point of your edit? You are not supposed to correct coding mistakes in edits, if it is substantial, it may be a base for an answer, otherwise for a comment. If you wanted to make the code compatible with the error message, you did not succeed in that either and I am not sure there is a way how to do that without changing too much.

Answer (score 5):

As francescalus stated in his comment, `A`, `B`, and `C` are declared as scalars inside the subroutine. Therefore, you cannot index them as arrays.

In this particular case I would rather use the intrinsic function `matmul` instead of writing your own matrix-matrix multiplication:

```
Program Matrix_Multiplication
  Implicit None
  Real, Dimension (2,2) :: A,B,C

  A=0.0
  B=0.0
  C=0.0
  do i=1,2
    do j=1,2
      Read (80,*) A(j,i)
      Read (90,*) B(j,i)
      Write (100,*) A,B
    end do
  end do

  C = matmul(A,B)
  Write (110,*) C
End Program Matrix_Multiplication
```

For larger matrices there are highly optimized math-libraries out there. Using BLAS/LAPACK is highly recommended then. The correct subroutine for your example would be [SGEMM](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/sgemm.html).

Answer (score 2):

More of a formatted comment than an answer but the declaration

```
Real, Dimension (2:2) :: A,B,C
```

declares `A`,`B` and `C` to be rank-1 arrays of 0 elements.  You probably ought to rewrite the statement as

```
Real, Dimension (2,2) :: A,B,C
```

which declares the arrays to be rank-2 and `2x2`.